# How to Iterate over JSON object or dictionary

Tags: python, json, api

I'm new to Python and I'm having trouble with a Json object. What would be the best way to do this iteration? I need to collect the Rank of all users)

//JSON file

```
"total": 2702,
"pageIndex": 1,
"pageSize": 100,
"data": [
  {
  "rank": 1,
  "handle": "saarixx",
  "color": "Red",
  "rating": 3249,
  "highestRatingType": "Design"
},
{
  "rank": 2,
  "handle": "kyky",
  "color": "Red",
  "rating": 2785,
  "highestRatingType": "Design"
},
{
  "rank": 3,
  "handle": "dmks",
  "color": "Red",
  "rating": 2575,
  "highestRatingType": "Design"
},
```

//What I tried

```
 response = requests.get("https://api.topcoder.com/v2/users/tops/develop/", params=pages)
 data = json.loads(response.text)

for i in data.items():
    print(data['data'][i]['rank'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `list` comprehension:

```
[user['rank'] for user in data['data']]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of different ways to do this, loop, list comprehension or my new favorite (and probably overkill) Pandas DataFrame.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://api.topcoder.com/v2/users/tops/develop/")
data = response.json()

player_stats = data['data']

player_stats_df = pd.DataFrame(player_stats)

player_stats_df
```

The above code generates a nice structured table.
[image]